# Ionic 3 keyboard issue on ion-input

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic3

[Issue when keyboard is up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ybWu.jpg)

I have a problem in my ionic3 app. As you can see in the picture, when the keyboard is open, the button "Registrarse" put on ion-inputs elements. 
The button "Registrarse" is on the bottom of the ion-content with position:absolute and bottom:5% CSS rules.

Can someone help me? I want that the keyboard hide or scroll up the whole content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class **hide-on-keyboard-open** in footer user position absolute.
**hide-on-keyboard-open** class work open keyboard to hide your footer
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/page/keyboard/

```
    <ion-footer-bar class="hide-on-keyboard-open">
      <div class="button-bar">
        <button class="button icon-right ion-pin">Post</button>
        <button class="button icon-right ion-person">My account</button>
        <button class="button icon-right ion-settings">Settings</button>
      </div>
    </ion-footer-bar>
```

Comment: That's for Ionic 1. The questions is related to Ionic 3

Comment: ion-footer-bar doesn't exist in Ionic 3

Comment: But ion-footer with the class "hide-on-keyboard-open" does the trick!!! Thank you @NikitBarochiya